# How can I check the current time on a droid device and put that into an integer?

Tags: android, date, time, integer

I know there is the Date() class built into the API, but what line of code actually grabs the time of day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) take a look at [link text](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds since 1970.  However, it's a long and will not fit into an integer.

```
Date now = new Date();
long millis = now.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

See [System](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) in Android docs for proper uses, but you could

```
import java.lang.System;

long now = System.getcurrentTimeMillis()
```